# How does a subview frame change if I transform the view frame?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, ios

I have to do this:

```
1:CGRect originalSubviewFrame = subview.frame;
2:view.frame = (CGRect)newFrame;
3:subview.frame = originalSubviewFrame;
```

I think instructions 1 and 3 shouldn't be there but if I don't restore the subview shape, it change for some reason!?!?
I read the documentation but it's unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `subview` is a subview of `view` then whether it's frame changes when `view`'s frame changed depends on whether `view.autoresizesSubviews` is `YES` and if so, how that manifests is determined by `subview.autoresizingMask`.

I encourage you to read the [`UIView` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) regarding those two properties.

Comment: Correct! Best answer for this type of animations. Thanks!